# Echo total loop count before/above the loop

Tags: php, variables

I want to echo the total count above the loop (image gallery). But the loop needs to run first. How to achieve this?

```
<?
$images = $dom2->getElementsByTagName('img');

// info block
echo 'Total images: ' . $i;

// the loop
$i = 0;                             
foreach ($images as $image) {
    echo "<img src='";
    echo $image->getAttribute('src');
    echo "'>";

    $i = $i + 1;

}
?>
```

Comment: What is `$images`? Something countable? E.g. `count($images)`…?

Comment: $i = $i + 1; can be written as $i++;

Comment: The opening tag `<?` is not safe. Always use `<?php`. You can safely omit the closing tag `?>` if there is nothing else after it in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `$images` is a [`DOMNodeList`](http://www.php.net/DOMNodeList), you can access its `$length` property:

```
echo 'Total images: ', $images->length;
```

Answer (score 5):

Just [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) the images:

```
<?php
// info block
echo 'Total images: ' . count($images);

// the loop
foreach ($images as $image)
    echo '<img src="' . $image->getAttribute('src') . '">';
```

***Updated (now we know that `$images` is [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) object):***

You can simply use the `$length` property:

```
<?php
// info block
echo 'Total images: ' . $images->length;
...
```

Comment: It returns 1 when there are 20 images.

Comment: @Jack Then what exactly *is* `$images`?

Comment: Then something must have changed inside `$images`. If `foreach` works, `count` works as well.

Comment: @mch Not necessarily, it depends on whether `$images` is countable.

Comment: @deceze `$images = $dom2->getElementsByTagName('img');`

Answer (score 0):

count the images,  echo count($images);

Comment: nice copy&paste from the previous answer (-;

Comment: @Neodan The answers were posted within 30 seconds of each other. I doubt it's a copy and paste.

Comment: Ok, but the answer quality is poor

Comment: yes, I was commenting from the mobile app, I didn't see the new comments...